# Xcode 6 Constraints with button images

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, storyboard

I am creating an app that have a dashboard with 11 images..

1 is the background, 1 are the lines that divide the button and 9 are the button with images.

I tried several times with the automatic constraints assignment but I also tried manually and I can't figure it out how to setup the constraints correctly. I followed also a lot of tutorial. If you watch the image below, you can see that the button/images especially in the iPhone 4 are weird!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you have to take a view which contains a button....after that just follow the below image for set up view constraints...You have 9 images ...I just gave you demo with 7 buttons

[image]

and for button there is just 4 constraints...I setup for one...you just need to follow for all buttons...

[image]

And here is the result image...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your Reply! is very great! I try it now.. so i need to create a view for each space?

Comment: the problem is that it's all like the first image i gave you

Comment: i know but i did all what you do in the images but it doesn't work.. can i share my desktop with Skype or team viewer ? anyway now i have 20 in reputation :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83842/discussion-between-bhavin-and-marcoc).

Answer (score 0):

Add all of the components into UIView and than set the constraints for UIView. These will help a lot to setup view.

Comment: i think it's already done that.. all components are into the View